# Powershell - Read a single text file and sort contents to multiple files based on text within the line

Tags: sorting, powershell, lines

I'm looking for some direction on how to read a file line by line, then copy the line based on a search criteria to a newly created file. Since my description is probably poor, I've tried to illustrate below:

```
Single Text File Sample:
Name=N0060093G
Name=N0060093H
Name=N400205PW
Name=N400205PX
Name=N966O85Q0
Name=N966O85Q1
```

The script would read each line and use the `"###"` after `"Name=N"`, to create a new file name after the identifier, `"###"` to copy each appropriate line to the new file. So, lines `"Name=N0060093G"`and `"Name=N0060093H"` would go to "**006**.txt"; `"Name=N400205PW"` and `"Name=N400205PX"` would write to "**400**.txt", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RegEx style approach:

```
$File = 'test.txt'
Get-Content $File | ForEach {
    If ($_ -match '^Name\=N(?<filename>\d{3}).*') {
        $_ | Out-File -Append "$($Matches.Filename).txt" -WhatIf
    }
}
```